# objective C SMS option crashes the entire App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sms

I am developping an iPhone App that sends SMS, I am using XCode 4.2

basically I need it to generate a body and to add a phone number to the receipient .

I ran the application on an iPad and it crashed the application , when I went through the code and found out that the receipient line is making the problem  when I remove this line it works perfectly fine and it directs to the messages application.

any clue how to avoid this problem ?

here is the Code I am using

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *sms = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        sms.recipients=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1111111111"];
        sms.body= @"test";
        sms.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:sms animated:YES];
    }
```

the log :

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Fri Sep 16 06:56:50 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-692-73
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 1
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 7
(gdb)
```

I get the following green error :

```
Tread1 : Program Received signal :"EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
```

and the following warning(yellow)

```
Missing sentinel dispatch
```

Comment: Maybe you want to post a crash log... And pay attention to your posted code. `[MFMessagecomposeViewController can send text]` is not valid in ObjC.

Comment: I edited my posted
here is the log that I am getting (I am new to the iphone Development and I think that this is what you need):
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Fri Sep 16 06:56:50 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.

Comment: We still need more infos... Crash log please!

Comment: By the way, I don't think MFMessagecomposeViewController has a `receipients`. Is it your actual code, or is it just a typo?

Comment: This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-692-73
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 1
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 7
(gdb)

Comment: Post it in your question... It's just unreadable in the comments.

Comment: it does has a receipients option, as I mentionned it works perfectly fine on iphone not ipads...

Comment: Are you really assigning a `MFMessageComposeController` to a `MFMessageComposeViewController`???

Comment: Thank you for not formatting correctly the log... Also, it's not a crash log, but a normal GDB session. No info here.

Comment: I was typing the code not pasting it , forgot to type "view" , I edited the question

Comment: Ok, voting to close... Did what I could... First check your code, and learn how to get a debug trace. Then come back with a real question, and please, format your code and check for this horrible typos!

Comment: ok , I pasted my code , and this one works

Comment: At last... By the way, did you also noticed the memory leak, as you don't release the `MFMessageComposeViewController` instance?

Comment: I did [sms release] , but i get the following 2 error (in red) :
-'release' is unavailable not available in automatic reference counting mode .
-ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'

Comment: Ok... My mistake... But next time tell us you are using ARC, we just can't guess...

Comment: I updated my question with the errors that i get , is this the log ?

Comment: See my answer. It's not a crash log, but now we can see what's wrong...

Comment: it works now , i had to add ",nil"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writing this as answer because i do not have privilege to comment.
i think the problem is with

```
sms.receipients=[NSArrayWithObjects:@"1111111111"];
```

which should be

```
 sms.receipients=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1111111111"];
```

EDIT :

```
  sms.receipients=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1111111111",nil];
```

or

```
  sms.receipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1111111111"];
```

Comment: A typo among the others, I guess... That code is just full of typos... : S

Comment: arrayWithObjects expects a nil at the end, use arrayWithObject

Comment: I copy pasted the code , now , I was typing it since I was using my PC

Answer (score 1):

```
sms.receipients=[NSArrayWithObjects:@"1111111111"];
```

isn't going to work. Nor is

```
sms.recipients=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1111111111"]
```

Try

```
sms.recipients=[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1111111111"];
```

arrayWithObjects requires a nil terminated list of objects. arrayWithObject just expects one object.

Comment: A typo among the others, I guess... That code is just full of typos... : S

Comment: 3 in one line is pretty impressive

Comment: Yep... Maybe his clipboard is also trying to learn Objective-C, without success...

Answer (score 0):

Now that you edited your question with the error you receive:

```
sms.recipients = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1111111111" ];
```

Needs to be:

```
sms.recipients = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1111111111", nil ];
```

You miss the `nil` sentinel, used to detect the end of the variable arguments of the `arrayWithObjects` method.